# Python: Sorting dictionary by key

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a dictionary by key.

If I do the following, then the dictionary is sorted like this

```
1, 20
10, 5
11, 3
2, 30
20, 2
```

Instead, I wanted to sort it like the following:

```
1, 20
2, 30
10, 5
11, 3
20, 2
```

My existing code

```
writer = csv.writer(open('something.csv', 'wb'))

keylist = count.keys()
keylist.sort()
for key in keylist:
    writer.writerow([key, count[key]])
```

Comment: It looks like your keys are strings, rather than numbers - that's lexicographical sorting.

Comment: Anyways I think such questions are already there on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can simply `keylist.sort(key=int)`,  you could also pass sorted to writerows `writer.writerows(sorted(count.items(),key=lambda x: int(x[0])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary keys are strings, so they are sorted alphabetically. You need to convert the keys to integers first:

```
keylist = [int(k) for k in count.keys()]
keylist.sort()

for key in keylist:
     writer.writerow([key, count[str(key)]])
```

Comment: `count.keys(key=int)` would be work as the OP does not need ints and  you would not have to cast again, you could also just iterate over the dict.